# Can not call JS and image files after login using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a issue in my app which has made using Node.js.I have a login page and when user logged in and redirect to next page the java script and image files can not call. I am explaining my code file below.

The following file is after user login.

> video.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Video</title>
<style>
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}

/***********************
  GRADIENT BUTTONS
************************/
.btn-primary.gradient {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%, #0099cc 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#33a6cc), color-stop(50%,#0099cc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #33a6cc 50%,#0099cc 50%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33a6cc', endColorstr='#0099cc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.btn-primary.gradient:hover, .btn-primary.gradient:focus, .btn-primary.gradient:active, .btn-primary.gradient.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #66b2cc 50%, #33a6cc 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#66b2cc), color-stop(50%,#33a6cc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #66b2cc 50%,#33a6cc 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #66b2cc 50%,#33a6cc 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #66b2cc 50%,#33a6cc 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #66b2cc 50%,#33a6cc 50%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#66b2cc', endColorstr='#33a6cc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.btn-primary.gradient:active, .btn-primary.gradient.active {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #267c99 50%, #007299 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#267c99), color-stop(50%,#007299)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #267c99 50%,#007299 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #267c99 50%,#007299 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #267c99 50%,#007299 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #267c99 50%,#007299 50%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#267c99', endColorstr='#007299',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/***********************
  CUSTON BTN VALUES
************************/

.btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}

.btn-primary {
    background: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background: #33a6cc;
}
.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
    background: #007299;
    box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Video broadcasting</h1>
<video  style="width:640px;height:360px;" poster="image/video-poster-frame.jpg" id="video">
<source src="video/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<source src="devstories.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg gradient" id="play_btn" style="display:none">Play/Pause</button>
<textarea id="id_url" rows="1" cols="2"></textarea>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    if(getQuery('usertype')){
        $('#play_btn').css('display','block');
    }
     videoBroadCasting(getQuery('id'));
}
function getQuery(key){
        var temp = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"));
        if(!temp) return;
        return temp[1];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My server file given below.

> server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var database='Oditek';
var collections=['video'];
var app= express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var db = mongo.connect("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
db.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/login.html');
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.userpassword;
    if(username && password){
        db.video.findOne({
            username:username,
            password:password
        },function(err,doc){
            if(doc){
                console.log('login',doc);
                res.send(doc);
            }
            if(err){
                console.log('login12',err);
                res.send("could not login");
            }
        });
    }
});
app.get('/video',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/video.html');
});
server.listen(port);
console.log('server is listening on the port'+port);
```

My all Javascript and image files are inside public folder.I am maintaining the below file structure .

`public->js->all .js files.`
`public->image->all images.`
`public->css->all .css files.`

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: You need to mention how you resolved it. It will benefit other developers who come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line

`<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` with

`<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The second script link resolved the issue.